# How to manage activity inheritance in Android Development

Tags: java, android, oop, inheritance, android-fragments

This is a relatively general question that I have regarding to Android development.

In the Android application, I am using SlidingMenu library. Imagine the activity I am trying to implement has a Navigation Drawer (from Sliding Menu Library) and action bar tabs with View Pager and contains different fragments.

In order to have the navigation drawer in the activity, I had to inherit the application from `SlidingActivity` like this:

```
public class ActivityMain extends SlidingActivity implements TabListener {
```

However, to make View Pager work in this activity, I will need to use Make a FragmentPagerAdapter instance, and if I want to use it, it requires the activity extend the `Fragment Activity`.

My Activity already extended `SlidingActivity`, so there is no way to extend another super class. I am not sure what will be a proper way to solve this conflict. When I was working on the Android app, I have saw some other cases that different components in one activity requires to extend from different super class. What will be the general solution to such problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the package of SlidingMenu [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/app), they have an activity called `SlidingFragmentActivity`. Extend this activity instead of `SlidingActivity` gives you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Activities in a SlidingMenu by constructing it programmatically `new SlidingMenu(Context context)` and then calling `SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(Activity activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW | SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT)`. `SLIDING_WINDOW` will include the Title/ActionBar in the content section of the SlidingMenu, while `SLIDING_CONTENT` does not. You can check it out in the example app AttachExample Activity.

from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu